# Upvoting/commenting/answering old questions

Tags: discusión

What is the rule about upvoting, commenting on, and answering old questions?

- If there is an old question that I have more information on, that is
  not included in current answers, should I add it? I know that the
  person who asked the question most likely no longer cares but other
  people who find the question might still benefit.
- How about adding comments for extra things that may not have been
  included originally?
- Lastly, what is the rule on upvoting old questions and answers (sorry
  if this should be a second question)

The reason I ask is that on forums, its considered bad to resurrect old threads.

Thanks =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, please add answers to old questions!  This makes the site more valuable.

The same goes for adding comments.

And up-voting (and likewise down-voting) is *always* appropriate.

The only time when I would suggest being weary of touching old posts is when you're editing or re-tagging a bunch of old questions at once.  It's still good to do this, if it improves the posts, but don't do 50 all at once, as that pushes 50 old posts to the front page, and pushes the newer posts off.  Limit your large edits of old posts to, say, 5 posts per day.

Comment: I disagree with the retagging pushing stuff off the front page. If you want a busy SE like StackOverflow / SuperUser / ServerFault you really ought to expect things to be moving a lot on what is actually the ["Active tab"](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/?tab=active). If you just want to see new questions look at the ["Newest tab"](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest).

Comment: @hippietrail: On a _busy_ site the dynamics of the front page are completely different. But even so, I also agree with you, but have been chided by the powers that be for such editing habits in the past; so now I fall in line. :)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what Flimzy said, feel absolutely free to edit the answers as you see fit, as long as you don't change the structure of the author. Feel free to add as much content as you want to an answer.

The site is a community for a community after all. Don't forget it! :)